# App crashes while parsing JSON

Tags: c#, json

I am getting some JSON data from a website using Newtonsoft.JSON

Earlier it was all working fine when I was only parsing 1 value. Recently, I needed more so I am now parsing 3 values. Unfortunately, now it takes even more time than it took normally (Why is it happening? Hasn't the JSON string been downloaded? ) and also, it crashes after a very long time. The stack shows it crashed at Settings1_Load

Code is here -

```
public void Settings1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var json = webClient.DownloadString("http://backpack.tf/api/IGetPrices/v3/?format=json&key=53195ef54dd7b8a9088b4567");
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject o = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
        value = (double)o["response"]["prices"][DefindexS]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"];
        price = (double)o["response"]["prices"][DefindexS]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"];
        currency = (string)o["response"]["prices"][DefindexS]["6"]["0"]["current"]["currency"];
        keyvalue = (double)o["response"]["prices"]["5021"]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"];

    }
    LoadText();        
}

public void LoadText()
{

    txtUsername.Text = UsernameS;
    txtPassword.Text = PasswordS;
    txtName.Text = DisplayNameS;
    txtPrefix.Text = PrefixS;
    txtBackpack.Text = BackpackS;
    txtSell.Text = AnyUserHandler.SellPricePerItem.ToString();
    txtBuy.Text = AnyUserHandler.BuyPricePerItem.ToString();
    txtDefindex.Text = DefindexS;
    textBox1.Text = NameS;
    if (currency == "metal")
    {
        lblPrice.Text = "Price: " + value.ToString() + " ref";
    }
    else if (currency == "keys")
    {
        lblPrice.Text = "Price: " + value.ToString() + " keys";
    }

}
```

I get this error - http://gyazo.com/e41baf3f17ccb6de1776eeefb74f8174

Comment: What error are you getting?  What line number does it crash on?

Comment: @JohnKoerner http://gyazo.com/e41baf3f17ccb6de1776eeefb74f8174

Comment: I did not get a null reference..

Answer (score 2):

I got it.

Instead of formatting realdef with quotes, I just used DefindexS.ToString() and it worked

```
value = (double)o["response"]["prices"][DefindexS.ToString()]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"];
```

This worked^

Answer (score 1):

You probably should look at the JSON result to see if the actual values that you are looking for is in the same order as your code.

But to keep things simpler, try to create a concrete class and de-serialize it using JSON.Net and follow the breakpoint to verify if the de-serialized object is accurate. You can even try creating the class automatically using http://json2csharp.com/

And for your question regarding using the variable `DefindexS`:

Use:

```
[String.Format("\"{0}\"", DefindexS.ToString())]
```

instead of

```
[DefindexS]
```

I think the JObject.GetValue Method (String) needs to be used here.

Instead of:

```
value = (double)o["response"]["prices"][DefindexS]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"];
```

Use:

```
value = (decimal)o.SelectToken(string.Format("response.prices.{0}.6.0.current.value", DefindexS.ToString()));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer though while debugging I have now figured out the problem.. When I use
currency = (string)o["response"]["prices"][DefindexS]["6"]["0"]["current"]["currency"];
it gives an error but if I replace defindexS with some number within double qotes. it works..

Comment: How do i do something like while parsing, it recognizes DefindexS as the number I want

Comment: Also, my keyvalue is working as it uses "5021" while the others aren;t

Comment: Use [String.Format("\"{0}\"", DefindexS.ToString())] instead of [DefindexS]

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: I did this and it worked:
price = (double)o["response"]["prices"]["5021"]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"];
                currency = (string)o["response"]["prices"]["5021"]["6"]["0"]["current"]["currency"];
                //keyvalue = (double)o["response"]["prices"]["5021"]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"]
                Console.WriteLine("price" + price);
                Console.WriteLine("Currency" + currency);

but when I format  the defindex to replace "5021" i get the error

Comment: Try my new edited answer. You'd need to use the JObject.GetValue method.

Comment: Error 1 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' does not contain a definition for 'GetValue' and no extension method 'GetValue' accepting a first argument of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I:\Trading Bots\Any-Item Bot\SteamBot\Settings1.cs 78 56 ExampleBot

Comment: Looks like the object is a JToken and not a JObject. Try the edited version now.

Comment: I answered me question and it worked. was quite simple meh

Comment: I thought you already tried that and it failed. Anyway, you can simplify the code by specifying the entire path of the json and avoid any further NullReference exception.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the help anyways :)